# Alternate forms of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{(n-k+1)}}{k! (n-k+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I ran across this sum when I was attempting to evaluate this Mellin transform:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} \: e^x \left( e^{e^{-x} \cdot e^{e^{-x}}}- e^{e^{-x}} \right) \: dx = \Gamma(s) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{(n-k+1)}}{k! (n-k+1)!} $$

The sum in question is symmetrical, that is:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{(n-k+1)}}{k! (n-k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-k+1)^k}{k! (n-k+1)!} $$

I understand a closed form for the finite sum is highly unlikely but was interested if anyone was aware of connections to other special functions.

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, I messed up the exponential bracketing.
For better visual parsing the expression between the parenthesis is
$$ \exp (\exp (-x) \cdot \exp (\exp (-x)))-\exp (\exp (-x)) $$

Comment: Where does the Mellin transform come from?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I was trying to solve another problem on this site posted by Pinteco by generalizing the integral via a Mellin Transform. So nothing special unfortunately.